# Wanted to load markers on maps asynchronously in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-markers

I am loading google map and then adding markers on map it usually takes 
4 to 7 seconds to load the map with markers but i want to improve 
performance of app so first i just want to show the map and in background 
i want to load markers and apply on map later. i tried so many ways like 
Task.Run(), Thread(threadStart()),RunonUiThread() nothing is working. 
RunonUiThread and threadstart is blocking UI and taking more time to load where in Task.Run is not loading the markers on map.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
          SetUpMap();
         }


    SetUpMap(){
        if (_map == null)
        {
            Utils.mapFrag = 
         (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
             //initializing map which is calling IOnMapReady 
                 asynchronously
                    Utils.mapFrag.GetMapAsync(this); 
                });

        }
        else
        {
            LoadMarkersOnMap(_map);
        }

    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        _map = googleMap;
        _map.UiSettings.MapToolbarEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        Utils.map = googleMap;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            LoadMarkersOnMap(_map);
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.IsShowing)
                progressDialog.Dismiss();
        });
  }

 LoadMarkerOnMap(Googlemap _map){
 RunOnUiThread(()=>{
 //here i m getting the list of markers from the database
 and adding it to map 

});

 }
```

even i tried without putting runonUithread still it is blocking ui or 
not loading markers properly. sometimes it load markers some times it do 
not load all markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Xamarin docs here: [Writing Responsive Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/writing-responsive-apps).

Comment: Thnak you so much. this was really very helpful. ThreadPool worked for me.

Comment: @CodeRunner Did it do the job using Google Maps, have the exact same need ?

Comment: Yes, I did it with google maps but I can't recall what I did exactly at that time. Now I already rewrote same application with flutter. So let me know if you need more help then I will look into old project and will give you some more reference or sample code.